# Why should one favor composition over inheritance? When should I choose to use composition rather than inheritance?

Tags: java, oop

In the text, Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, he states 'Instead
of extending an existing class, give your new class a private field that references
an instance of the existing class. This design is called composition because the
existing class becomes a component of the new one.' He further adds that one should always prefer composition over inheritance. Is this generally applicable to all general programming scenarios? Till now I have always used inheritance and considered it to be a solid concept. In what context should one decide to use composition?

Comment: One use case may be when you need to use classes from a third party API in your project and need some specific functionality, but these classes are marked as `final` so you cannot extend them.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's not preferring to use composition, that's being forced to use composition.